# From an end-effector trajectory to joints movements

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, motion-planning

let's assume that our robot consists of 3 degree-of-freedoms. In order to move the end-effector of this robot along a straight line, these 3 joints have moved as below:

[image]

Now, if the desired end-effector trajectory is changed, how can I deduce from this deviation of end-effector trajectory, the correspond joint movements?

Comment: "desired end-effector trajectory is changed" -- why can't you use the same method you used to calculate IK for straight line end-effector motion?

Comment: Of course, I could calculate afresh with an IK-solver. However, I am wondering whether one can deduce the appropriate set of joint movements from the change in the ee-trajectory.

Comment: Can you add units to your graph?